# Putting images as axis ticks in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

is it possible to put images as axis ticks using d3.js javascript library? 
I am trying to visualize a simple bar graph (done!) but in the x-axis I need to show a different image for each bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible.  The way to think about this is using d3 to position images on a page.

If you have each image in a div with it's own id then you can [use d3 to select and position](http://d3js.org/) those divs.  I found [this tutorial](http://www.recursion.org/d3-for-mere-mortals/) very helpful.